# XCode Formatting

Tags: xcode, formatting, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a short cut or some quick way for Xcode to format this code:

```
if(x==10){
if(y=100){
//Do this
}
}
```

To this:

```
if(x==10){
    if(y=100){
        //Do this
    }
}
```

Sometimes the logic of the code can get a little hard to read. I seem to spend a lot of time making the code easier to read.

Comment: Highlight, RMB, and select the "format/indent" option.  I don't have a Mac here to check the exact wording.

Comment: Highlight the text and press control-i. Or choose "Re-Indent" on the "Structure" menu on the "Editor" menu in Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a short cut or some quick way for Xcode to format this code

**Yes.** Use the Editor->Structure->Re-indent command (the default keyboard equivalent is control-I). If you don't have anything selected, I think it just indents the line with the insertion point. If you select multiple lines and use the command, it'll do all the selected lines.

Answer (score 0):

Select the text then  ctrl + I that will do what you want

Comment: Perhaps you could also provide a link to where XCode key combos are set?

Comment: That works after editing the shortcuts in preference.

Comment: http://www.git-tower.com/blog/xcode-cheat-sheet. Please  refer to the "editing".   Fix Indentation

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Swift for development

You can try my plugin: [Swimat](https://github.com/Jintin/Swimat)

It can format your code into:

```
if (x == 10) {
    if (y = 100) {
        // Do this
    }
}
```

See https://github.com/Jintin/Swimat for more information